# Print uwp app using programmatically webview

Tags: xamarin, printing, uwp

I have a simple `WebView` like:

```
 var webView = new Xamarin.Forms.WebView
            {
                Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
                {
                    Html = @$"
                            <!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html>
                            <body>
<table border = '1'; style='width:265; height:189;'>
    <caption>SLOT CARD</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>QR</th>
        <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>
            value1
            value2
            value3
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
                            </body>
                            </html>
                            "
                }
            };
```

As you can see I create webView programmatically, I don't use XAML page to do this. So I want to know how to print this html web view, I saw a lot of examples but they are incomplete or very hard to understand. Can someone know some library or how to print this using something like:

```
  PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
            document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Test";
            document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = document.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[0];
            document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(1, 1, 1, 1);
       

            document.Print();
```

How can I attach my webview there? is that possible? Regards

Note*: My webview concist in only one page with short table... Max size of table inside webview is : 265px x 189px

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about printing a UWP webview

Comment: That is for android onlt @SushiHangover

Comment: You could take a look at the [Print Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/printhelper)